# Javascript closure

Tags: javascript

I read the () at the end of the closure will execute it immediately. So, what is the difference between these two. I saw the first usage in some code.

thanks.

```
for (var a=selectsomeobj(),i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
        (function(val){
            anotherFn(val);
        })(a[i]);
}

for (var a=selectsomeobj(),i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
            anotherFn(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this example there are no differences. In both cases, `anotherFn` gets executed immediately.

However, an immediate function is often used when a function is created in a loop.

Consider this example (more or less pseudo code):

```
for(var i from 1..10) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
         alert(values[i]);
    }
}
```

As JavaScript has only function scope, no block scope, all the event handlers share the same `i`, which will have the value `10` after the loop finished. So every handler will try to alert `values[10]`.

By using an immediate function, a new scope is introduced which "captures" the current value of the loop variable:

```
for(var i from 1..10) {
    (function(index) {
        elements[i].onclick = function() {
             alert(values[index]);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

As this is sometimes hard to read, creating a standalone function which returns another function is often better:

```
function getHandler(value) {
     return function(){alert(value);};
}

for(var i from 1..10) {
     elements[i].onclick = getHandler(values[i]);
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try to use for(var i from 1..10) {}

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: Yes it's not JavaScript. Note that I wrote *"Consider this example (more or less **pseudo code**):"*

Answer (score 3):

In both instances in your example the values do identical operations. There are other examples out there where if you're not careful to use the first method (with the self-executing anonymous function), the value of `i` will increment and not be passed correctly to your function.

Here's a guide, scroll down to the **creating closures in loops: a common mistake** section to see the problem:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 1):

the first defines a [self-invoking function](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/ask-jw-decoding-self-invoking-anonymous-functions/) (which in turn executes a function), the second just executes the function.  In both cases the argument passed to the is a[i].

Comment: any difference in effect.. or the program behaves the same?

Comment: i added a link that explains the self invoking function -- in this case there is no reason to use one.

Comment: No, in this case, there's no difference, because the closure is practically empty.