# How can I simplify this?

Tags: jquery, html

So I want to simplify this into one function but I don't know how to. It seems that I should be able to pull the variable from the click ids and then use it in the hidden id selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
    $("#click1").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden1").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden1").animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
        $("#hidden1").stop();
        });  
    $("#click2").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden2").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden2").animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
        $("#hidden2").stop();
        });  
    $("#click3").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden3").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden3").animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
        $("#hidden3").stop();
        });  
    $("#click4").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden4").animate({opacity:'0'});
        $("#hidden4").animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
        $("#hidden4").stop();
        });  
    });


    <p id="click1">hover</p>
    <p id="click2">hover</p>
    <p id="click3">hover</p>
    <p id="click4">hover</p>

    <p id="hidden1" class="hidden">hidden 1</p>
    <p id="hidden2" class="hidden">hidden 2</p>
    <p id="hidden3" class="hidden">hidden 3</p>
    <p id="hidden4" class="hidden">hidden 4</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$(".hidden").css({opacity:'0'});
$("p[id^=click]").click(function(){
    var sufix = this.id.substring(5);
    var el = $("#hidden" + sufix);
    $(".hidden").stop().not(el).animate({opacity:'0'});
    el.animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eaSWK/3/)

You if want a better performance use `$('#click1, #click2, #click3, #click4')` instead of `$("p[id^=click]")`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about substring.

Answer (score 0):

give all your hover-p's the same class, e.g. `clickable`.

I haven't tested the call to `index`, but it should work so or similar...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
      $(".clickable").click(function(){
          $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
          var idx = "#hidden" + $(".clickable").index(this);
          $(idx).animate({opacity:'0'});
          $(idx).animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
          $(idx).stop();
      });  
 });
```

edit: or use Arun P Johny's selector for extra points: `p[id^=click]`

Answer (score 0):

Split the tags into a shared class `click` and a unique tag, say `index`. Then listen for elements of the shared class to be clicked in general.

Inside the click callback you can get the actual clicked element using `$(this)`. From that we get the `index` tag using `attr('index')`. Given that we can apply animations only to the related hidden object.

Therefore first fetch all hidden objects with `$(".hidden")` and then apply a filter to find the element with the correct `index` tag with `.filter('[index="' + number + '"]')`.

HTML

```
<p class="click" index="1">hover</p>
<p class="click" index="2">hover</p>
<p class="click" index="3">hover</p>
<p class="click" index="4">hover</p>

<p class="hidden" index="1">hidden 1</p>
<p class="hidden" index="2">hidden 2</p>
<p class="hidden" index="3">hidden 3</p>
<p class="hidden" index="4">hidden 4</p>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.hidden').animate({ opacity:'0' });

    $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').animate({ opacity:'0' });

        var number = $(this).attr("index");

        $('.hidden').filter('[index="' + number + '"]')
               .animate({ opacity:'0' })
               .animate({ opacity:'1' },"slow")
               .stop();
    });
});
```

Moreover you can shorten the code by chaining functions executed on the same object like shown above.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHcXQ/) containing the code above. (Just for fun I made a [styled version](http://jsfiddle.net/SHcXQ/6/), too.)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know I could chain functions like that.

Comment: @MatthewPoulson. Check out the styled version which includes some general improvements not related to your question. By the way, if one of the answers solved your question you should mark that as accepted. Therefore simply click on the tick mark next to the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` attribute. It is easy to use, clear to understand and it is valid.

```
<p class="click" data-id="1">hover</p>
<p class="click" data-id="2">hover</p>
<p class="click" data-id="3">hover</p>
<p class="click" data-id="4">hover</p>

<p class="hidden" data-id="1">hidden 1</p>
<p class="hidden" data-id="2">hidden 2</p>
<p class="hidden" data-id="3">hidden 3</p>
<p class="hidden" data-id="4">hidden 4</p>


<script>
    function get_by_data(selector, data_string, data_value) {
        return $(selector + '[data-' + data_string + '="' + data_value + '"]');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hidden').animate({opacity: '0'});
        $('.click').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var $hidden = get_by_data('.hidden', 'id', id);
            $('.hidden').animate({opacity: '0'});
            $hidden.animate({opacity:'1'},'slow').stop();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm. Now I just need to understand it.

Comment: @MatthewPoulson Using `data`, you can define your own attributes of html tags (it's very cool sometimes). Here i define `data-id` attribute. To select element via data attribute you should write e.g `$('.click[data-id="1"]')`, but it's tough way when `id` is js variable, so i use function `get_by_data` which has `selector`, `data attribute name` and `data value` as arguments and returns jQuery object. Function `data('id')` is standart jQuery function, it returns value in data attribute of the element

Comment: why is `function get_by_data(selector, data_string, data_value) {
        return $(selector + '[data-' + data_string + '="' + data_value + '"]');
    }` not in the `$(document).ready(function() {...}` block?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for, from 1 to 4. And then inside you can have

```
$("#click" + index).click(function(){
    $(".hidden").animate({opacity:'0'});
    $("#hidden" + index).animate({opacity:'0'});
    $("#hidden" + index).animate({opacity:'1'},"slow");    
    $("#hidden" + index).stop();
    });
```

Comment: be careful about closures.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874041/javascript-closure/5874111#5874111) for a summary, and there are a lot of other resources on the topic in javascript. Also FYI, I'm not the downvoter